# JAVA: How to input a name and get their birthday

Tags: java, arrays

Mostly need to know why my code stops right before my second `for` loop.

> "Write an application that allows a user to enter the names and birth dates of up to 10 friends. Continue to prompt the user for names and birth-dates until the user enters the sentinel value “ZZZ” for a name or has entered 10 names, whichever comes first.
>
> When the user is finished entering names, produce a count of how many names were entered, and then display the names. In a loop, continuously ask the user to type one of the names and display the corresponding birth-date or an error message if the name has not been previously entered. The loop continues until the user enters “ZZZ” for a name."

I've spent hours upon hours on this and feel like i'm getting close but this is due in 4 hours and i really need help. I'm wondering why my program stops before it gets to my second loop. Also wondering if it can be improved. Thank you so very much in advance!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BirthdayReminder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String birth[] = new String[10];
        String names[] = new String[10];
        String a[] = new String[100];
     
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter name");
            names[i]= input.nextLine();

            if(names[i].equals("ZZZ"))
            {
                System.out.println(i); 
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));           
                break;
            }
            else if(i==10)
            {
                System.out.println(i+1);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
                for(int j=0;j>0;j++)
       
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Birthday");
                birth[i]= input.nextLine();
                System.out.println(names[i]);
            }
        }

    System.out.println("Enter name to get their Birthday");

    for(int j=0;j>0;j++){
        a[j]= input.nextLine();

        for(int k=0; k<10;k++)
            if(a[j]==names[k])
                System.out.println(birth[k]);
            else
                System.out.println("Name not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't stop before, it skips it entirely because 0 is not greater than 0.

Comment: Do you know about `debugging` function in IDE?

Comment: Gotcha, ugh sorry guys, the debugger didn't catch that one.

Comment: Noticed some other off stuff about this code too and i think i should be good now

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i correct based on your code. 
It works during my test.you can compare the difference between them.
For other better solutions, I suggest you Create a Entry class People , use while loop and Map data structure to  solve this problem.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class BirthdayReminder
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String birth[] = new String[10];
            String names[] = new String[10];
            String a[] = new String[100];

            for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter name");
                names[i]= input.nextLine();
                if(names[i].equals("ZZZ"))
                {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
                    break;
                }
                else if(i==10)
                {
                    System.out.println(i+1);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
                    for(int j=0;j>0;j++)

                        break;


                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter Birthday");
                    birth[i]= input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(names[i]);
                }

            }



            for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
                System.out.println("Enter name to get their Birthday");
                input = new Scanner(System.in);
                a[j]= input.nextLine();
                boolean valid = false;
                for(int k=0; k<10;k++){
                    if(a[j].equals(names[k])){
                        System.out.println(birth[k]);
                        valid = true;
                    }else if (k == 9 && !valid){
                        System.out.println("Name not found");
                    }

                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks man! Really good to know different techniques that can make things easier. This is what i came up with and it works :D

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BirthdayReminder
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String birth[] = new String[10];
String names[] = new String[10];
String a[] = new String[100];

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   {
   System.out.println("Enter name");
   names[i]= input.nextLine();
   if(names[i].equals("ZZZ"))
   {
        System.out.println(i); 
       for(int x=0; x<=i; x++)
       {
       System.out.println(names[x]);           
    }
    break;
    }

    else if(i==9)
   {
       System.out.println(i+1);
       for(int y=0; y<10; y++)
       {
       System.out.println(names[y]); 
    }  
    }
   else
   {
    System.out.println("Enter Birthday");
    birth[i]= input.nextLine();

   }
}
System.out.println("Enter name to get their Birthday");
for(int j=1;j>0;j++){
   a[j]= input.nextLine();
   if(a[j].equals("ZZZ"))
   break;
   for(int k=0; k<10;)
    if(a[j].equals(names[k]))
    {
     System.out.println(birth[k]);
     break;
    }
     else if(k<10&&!a.equals(names[k]))
     k++;
     else
     System.out.println("Name not found");
    }

}
```

}